# Matplotlib imshow and secondary x and y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

Let's say I have a picture taken with a sensor where the pixel size is 1mm.
I would like to show the image with `imshow`: the main axes should show the pixel while the secondary axes should show the mm.

`frassino.png` is the following picture

[image]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np

a = cv2.imread('frassino.png')
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(a,aspect='equal')
ax.set_xlabel('pixel')
ax.set_ylabel('pixel')
ax.figure.savefig('1.png')
```

`1.png` is the following picture, all is fine (I need the pixel to be square and so I add the argument `aspect='equal'`.

[image]

Now I add a secondary y axis:

```
v2 = ax.twinx()
v2.set_yticks(np.linspace(0,48,12))
v2.set_xlabel('mm')
ax.figure.savefig('2.png')
```

`2.png` is the following picture and I have two problems: first, the image is cropped and the upper part of the tree, like the foreground grass, is not visible; second, the `mm` label is truncated.

[image]

Now I add the secondary x axis:

```
h2 = ax.twiny()
h2.set_xticks(np.linspace(0,64,8))
h2.set_xlabel('mm')
ax.figure.savefig('3.png')
```

The following picture is `3.png`, the `mm` label is there but the image is still cropped.

[image]

How can the crop be avoided?

How can the y `mm` label be fixed?

Comment: The second question is due to typo:  you wrote `v2.set_xlabel('mm')` instead of `v2.set_ylabel('mm')`

Comment: @AndreySobolev Thank you, I've fixed the typo; now the label is just slightly truncated :-)

Comment: For the truncated label, you can call `plt.tight_layout()`, which usually solves this type of issues.

Comment: You want to adjust the right side of your figure so that the label fits. I added `fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.850)` between the figure creation and `ax.imshow`. This has to be done before imshow because the `aspect="equal"` will make further changes throw runtime errors.

Comment: Did you try a ["secondary" axis](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html) instead of `twinx()` and `twiny()`.  Such a secondary axis only add extra labels, while `twinx()` internally creates a new transparent subplot on top of the existing one.  (Also related: [imshow with second y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255824/matplotlib-imshow-with-second-y-axis), but is unclear whether you have the same issue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on an example found in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html), it seems the solution is to use **secondary** axes rather than **twin** axes. That will prevent datalim conflicts between the axes holding the image and the other ones that are only there to hold a different scale and ticks but no artist.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np

a = cv2.imread('frassino.png')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(a, aspect='equal')
ax.set_xlabel('pixel')
ax.set_ylabel('pixel')
ax.figure.savefig('1.png')

def px_to_mm(values):
    return values/10

def mm_to_px(values):
    return 10*values

v2 = ax.secondary_yaxis('right', functions=(px_to_mm, mm_to_px))
v2.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, 64, 12, endpoint=True))
v2.set_ylabel('mm')
ax.figure.savefig('2.png')

h2 = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(px_to_mm, mm_to_px))
h2.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 48, 8, endpoint=True))
h2.set_xlabel('mm')
ax.figure.savefig('3.png')
```

[image]